# Displaylink don't work if I close the lid of my laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, displaylink

I'm desperately trying to get my XPS 13 9350 (bios rev. 1.13.0, Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.8.0-50-generic) to work with my Dell 6000 dockstation and the two attached -- via displayport -- MSI Optix AG32CQ monitors. I have downloaded and installed the latest Displaylink driver (release 5.4). All works fine with one exception, if the lid of the laptop is closed the graphics of the two monitors get corrupted and the mouse can not act on the displayed windows. This is most frustrating.

The strange thing is also that the xrandr command list the two monitors connected via the DP cables as DVI-I-1-1 and DVI-I-2-2 and not as DP-1 and DP-2. Is this alright?

Comment: Just some feedback here on this problem. This was eventually solved by a kernel update. If you today is using the latest released kernel for 20.04 you will not experience this problem.